# How do I use with-type to use Typed Racket fragments within untyped modules?

Tags: scheme, racket, typed-racket

The [Typed Racket reference](http://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-reference/Typed_Regions.html) indicates that it's possible to use [`with-type`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-reference/Typed_Regions.html#%28form._%28%28lib._typed-racket%2Ftyped-racket..rkt%29._with-type%29%29) to created “typed regions” within untyped code.

> The [`with-type`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-reference/Typed_Regions.html#%28form._%28%28lib._typed-racket%2Ftyped-racket..rkt%29._with-type%29%29) form allows for localized Typed Racket regions in otherwise untyped code.

It’s a little unclear how to actually *use* this, though. Obviously, using such a feature needs to take place within an untyped module using `#lang racket` or something similar. How should the `with-type` binding be imported?

A naïve attempt is just to `require` Typed Racket, but this causes failures with how TR overwrites existing syntactic forms.

```
(require typed/racket)

(struct point (x y)) ; complains about missing type annotations
```

Trying to use `only-in` to simply require `with-type` and nothing else sort of works, but then none of the required type bindings (such as `Number` or `->`) exist.

It seems like the only way to do this would be to manually use `only-in` to import only the things that I need, but this feels laborious. I could also use `prefix-in`, but then of course everything would be scattered with prefixes.

Is there a recommended way of doing this, or is this feature somewhat deprecated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use `except-in` (or perhaps `rename-in`) to avoid the few identifiers that don't work in both typed and untyped programs. Like this modification of Greg's program:

```
#lang racket/base

(require (except-in typed/racket struct))

(struct point (x y))

(let ([x 'hello])
  (with-type
    #:result String
    #:freevars ([x String])
    (string-append x ", world")))
```

Comment: I'll accept this as the "canonical" answer. I wish it were nicer, but I can't really see a better way being possible without doing anything really crazy.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the fundamental answer. A guess is that it's the sort of thing that would be useful when writing macros, as opposed to code you'd write directly?

A practical idea: You can use `local-require` to limit the "contamination" of the TR require. And you can flip to using `except-in` if that's less work then `only-in`.

For instance this example from the docs get close, but gives a weird error presumably because it's using TR's `quote`:

```
#lang racket/base

(let ([x 'hello])
  (local-require typed/racket)
  (with-type
    #:result String
    #:freevars ([x String])
    (string-append x ", world")))
; /tmp/so.rkt:7:21: quote: identifier used out of context
;   in: quote
```

Excluding that with `except-in` gives the desired error:

```
(let ([x 'hello])
  (local-require (except-in typed/racket quote))
  (with-type
    #:result String
    #:freevars ([x String])
    (string-append x ", world")))
; x: broke its contract
;   promised: String
;   produced: 'hello
;   in: String
;   contract from: /tmp/so.rkt
;   blaming: /tmp/so.rkt
;    (assuming the contract is correct)
;   at: /tmp/so.rkt:14.17
```

But yeah. This is just fiddling with the edges and not getting to the heart of it.